# Status message not appearing when using setStatusTip() function with a TreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I was told the setToolTip() doesn't work on all platforms, therefore, I'm trying to use setStatusTip() to display a status message instead. But unfortunately, with the TreeWidgetItem the status bar is not getting updated. Nothing happens when I hover over the item.

Comment: according to documentation, the [QTreeWidget mouse tracking needs to be enabled for this feature to work](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setStatusTip). You can try to call `setMouseTracking(True)` in your `QTreeWidget` class

Comment: This worked, thank you! I was scratching my head on this for a long time..I thought since tooltips were working that mouse tracking was enabled.

Comment: I am glad it helped. I made an answer so users can easily find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The mouse tracking needs to be True on the QTreeWidget class to enable the status tips.

For this you need to call `setMouseTracking(True)` on your QTreeWidget class.